# Blog posts and the common layer

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using Joomla to design a website, very simple, there is a page on my site that is to store all news headlines (each is href) and each href leads to a full article, I would like to post an image in all of the articles, where can I put my image into in joomla folders so that right after each article title, the image will be shown ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To insert image in each article you have to follow this steps:

1. Administration->go to Article manager->CLick on article(view the article detail).
   2.Now you can see the edition where you putted your article content.now on same editor there is an option of image.select it and choose image from the folder in which you putted the images.
2. now apply or save the article.

hence you will add image to each article in joomla.

Comment: let me know if any problems in above steps.

Comment: Thank you, you are hilarious.:D.  I know how to insert images into a the article

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images into any folder you want. All you have to do is go to each article in the backend and manually insert an image by typing in the path. Easier thing to do would be to create a folder in the "images" folder so that the insert path isn't too long.

As fr inserting, I'm not sure if you wanted all the images to be inserted automatically, but I am pretty sure this isn't possible.